# When Developing a Program for 10+ Users

Tags: c#, database, desktop-application, erp

I'm relatively new to programming and I'm trying to develop a desktop program in C# that can help small businesses to do their daily tasks (purchase orders, sales orders, accounting, etc). The program will probably be for up to 10 users, but I consider the fact that the number of the user may grow, so it should be able to handle 10+ users.

My question is how does the database part of those kind of programs work. I mean it obviously should have a database, but if I put a database in it then should I pay for the database software every time that I sell it to a new customer? Also I'd appreciate ideas about which databases are good to use for that kind of a program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is asking about database licencing agreements and recommendations. Please read the help: [help/on-topic]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about database licencing agreements and recommendations

Comment: Database is free, you can create as many database as you want, you can also give out the database to others freely. SQL server Express is quite a good database to start with.

Answer (score 3):

If I was doing that I would look into sql Express. It will take quite a while for you to out grow it(if ever) and by then you can look into something else

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your scope. Let's say that you're a consultant of some sort and building this for different organizations. This would require that each organization have it's own database which would then mean, you can go with the free version of SQL or the paid version (they will have this setup for you).

However, if you're developing this program for one organization and their isn't a requirement to keep data isolated from one unit or another, you could just setup the free version of SQL or paid version and use that for everyone.

From the programming piece, your program, web based, or windows application, can be coded a couple of different ways. You can get into complex things such as creating stored procedures that are invoked by your application or just setup something in your program to push and pull data. There is a hell of a lot of information out there on how to do this. Keep in mind, you'll want to think of how the access rights will be handled (some users may be able to only read from the DB whereas some can read and write). Then of course there is encryption and hashing and all that good stuff, but that'll be on you to figure out.

Here's a basic example of creating a record in SQL via C#:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=myTestDb;server=(local)"))
{
    SqlCommand addSite = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO site_list (site_name) VALUES (@site_name)", conn);
    addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site_name", "mywebsitename");
    addSite.Connection.Open();
    addSite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    addSite.Connection.Close();
```